# Routing to a specific route URL directly in angular4

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing, angular-router

[image: Project Structure]

The project structure of my project. I am following angulars guide for arranging your project in modules here. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-4-crisis-center-feature

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'portal',
    canActivate: [RuntimeEnvironmentService],
    loadChildren: 'app/portal/portal.module#PortalModule',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [RuntimeEnvironmentService],
    loadChildren: 'app/features/features.module#FeaturesModule',
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: environment.preloadAllLazyLoadedModules
        ? PreloadAllModules
        : NoPreloading,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

If user navigates to http://localhost:4200 I want the user to be directed to FeaturesModule which works fine.

But when user navigates to http://localhost:4200/portal I want that user to be directed to the components in the PortalModule which does not work.

Snapshot of features-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FeaturesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'map-page',
        component: MapPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'map-page',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class FeaturesRoutingModule {}
```

Snapshot of portal-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'portal',
    component: PortalComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]

  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})
export class PortalRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html just has nothing but just one router-outlet tag

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

features.component.html has its own html and also one router-outlet tag to display the map component.

portal.component.html has this at the moment

```
<p>
  portal works! Why this is not displayed !!!
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</p>
```

Snapshot of AppModule

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { PortalModule } from './portal/portal.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    PortalModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // use hash location strategy or not based on env
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: environment.hashLocationStrategy
        ? HashLocationStrategy
        : PathLocationStrategy,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Snapshot of the features.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
            SharedModule,
            FeaturesRoutingModule,
            AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
              apiKey: 'AIzaSyAzGVaB4-VPQvIKlhcxz_uy2ft8uCPMZP4'
            })
  ],
  declarations: [
            FeaturesComponent,
            MapPageComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
            SkymeetService
  ]
})
export class FeaturesModule {}
```

Snapshot of the portal.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    PortalRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PortalComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ]
})
export class PortalModule { }
```

Since I have imported PortalModule in the AppModule I can see console.log in the ngOninit() of the PortalComponent class and LoginComponent class but the HTML does not get loaded. There is no error displayed. If I don't import PortalModule class then nothing is displayed.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router merges all routes into one array once it loads children, so when it merges your `forRoot` configuration with `forChild` you get:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: 'portal',
        canActivate: [RuntimeEnvironmentService],
        children: {
            path: 'portal',
            component: PortalComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: LoginComponent
                }
            ]
        }
```

So to navigate to `PortalComponent`, the route should be:

```
portal/portal
```

If you want to use `/portal` only, you need to change `forChild` configuration to:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PortalComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I did it still the HTML in the portal.component.html and login.component.html does not load but the console.logs inside the ngOnInit functions in both these components is called

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I did it still the HTML in the portal.component.html and login.component.html does not load but the console.logs inside the ngOnInit functions in both these components is called

Comment: @codestruggle, that's not possible. If you the component is loaded, the html should be shown. Can you try to reproduce it in the plunker/stackblitz?